# Problem converting Keras Models into Layers API format models to use with tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I have a Problem converting Keras Models into Layers API format models to use with tensorflowjs

I use the command:

```
$ tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras kerasModels/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5 convertedModels/
```

I get an error "KeyError: Can't open attribute (can't locate attribute 'keras version')"

Here is an image of the error log:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are trying to convert the model downloaded from [here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases), which is possibly outdated now.

You can download the VGG16 model fresh from [keras-applications](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications) using the following python script:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
model = VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
model.save("VGG16.h5")
```